# HAXM error (VT-x enabled, NX XD bit setting on)

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, virtualization, haxm

When I am installing Intel HAXM I have the following error:

> This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled.

I have checked my BiOS, VT-x is supported, and I enabled Intel virtualization. I also have checked if it was really enabled with the Intel virtualization technology detection tool (Intel Processor Identification Utility) and it says:

> Intel(R) Virtualization Technology - Yes

I've successfully turned on NX, XD setting. By inputting this code in admin cmd:

```
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
```

I've tried to install HAXM from both the Intel website (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) and Android Studio. In Avast, I've disabled "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: *Settings > Troubleshooting*. 
BUT when I try again to install HAXM I have the same error as the beginning of my message. Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also discovered this issue and was able to fix it by **uninstalling** Avast. 
To disable the features in Avast wasn't enough. 
Don't forget to restart after uninstall.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I would never have guessed. I had no problems with android studio afterwards as well.